# Background images won't print properly in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

My background images won't print properly if I create a PDF.

I've tried *Page Layout » Page Color » Fill effect » Picture* which looks fine on the screen, but it is skewed in the print preview and when creating a PDF, the image is tiled and all over the place.

When I remove the image from the background, everything works – the print background is checked in the options dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

If it's suitable, you can try using a real image in the background or the header\footer instead and see if that works better.